# Telegram Web Apps method Expand isn't working

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I found that the method Expand of window.Telegram.WebApp object isn't working in the Telegram client for Windows and IOS on computers and tablets.
How to increase the size of Web Apps frame for those devices?

Answer (score 0):

```
function buttonOn(){
     // do something on btn click
}

let main_page = document.querySelector('#main_page');


if  (main_page){
    window.Telegram.WebApp.expand() //expand window after page loading

    window.Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.onClick(buttonOn) //set func on main button click
    window.Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.setParams({'text': 'Корзина'}) // set byn params
    window.Telegram.WebApp.MainButton.show() //show telegram btn
}
```

Other button [events](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#events-available-for-web-apps)

Comment: I've tried this code. Unfortunately it isn't work in Windows desktop telegram client too.

Comment: I will edit answer later.  I have a new method.

Comment: @VladimirF3R Try this. I also added some telegram button function. Here is my tg bot username 'tyk_tyk_food_bot'

Comment: only starts working after page refresh for me

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line from the function:

```
window.Telegram.WebApp.expand() //expand window after page loading
```

And call it ***in the beginning***/***at the top*** of your main javascript code. (The code that will start running once the user has clicked on the button)

Also, you can make your code a lot shorter by putting `window.Telegram.WebApp` in a variable like:

```
const tele = window.Telegram.WebApp; //Initializes the TELEGRAM BOT and
  //Gets the user's Telegram ID from the Telegram API

tele.expand(); //Expands the app on the users' phone to 100% height
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, probably, you are a bit incorrect in understanding what "expansion" is. This term could only be applied to mobile devices with OS such as Android or iOS. Web App is displayed there in such native component as BottomSheet with inserted WebView containing your web application. Initially, in mobile devices, application is being opened minimized (not expanded). To make it use maximum allowed height of screen, you could call `expand()` method. It must work through `window.Telegram.WebApp.expand()`.

In desktop or web versions of Telegram, Web App is displayed in separate component which is not allowed to change its size.

You could probably find more useful information about viewport and expansion [here](https://telegram-web-apps.github.io/twa/docs/features/viewport), or use alternative libraries, such as [`twa-bridge`](https://telegram-web-apps.github.io/twa/docs/libraries/twa-bridge) or [`twa-sdk`](https://telegram-web-apps.github.io/twa/docs/libraries/twa-sdk/about)